# Android Fullscreen Fragment Dialog Background Clickable

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I have fullscreen fragment dialog. While it is showing, background objects can be clickable or interact with user. how do i avoid this?

Here is piece of code how i show dialog:

MainActivity.java

```
FullScreenFrDialog fr = new FullScreenFrDialog();

FragmentTransaction tr = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tr.add(android.R.id.content, fr, FR_TAG).commit();
```

FullScreenFrDialog.java

```
public class FullScreenFrDialog extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

}

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#CCFFFFFF" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</FrameLayout>
```

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This button clickable, while dialog is showing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add `setCancelable(false);` in `onCreateView(...)`

Comment: @MD i have tried this, but it is clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="#CCFFFFFF" >
```

Make the parents clickable true, hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` simply call `setCancelable(false)`. This will prevent the dialog from closing if tapped outside the dialog and will also prevent tap events to the elements beneath

**EDIT**

Alternatively you can call `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` if you want it to be dismissed with a back button press but still prevent touches to elements beneath

Comment: I have tried to put setCancelable(false) to onCreate() or onCreateView() but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ssmm did you try `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`?

Comment: I have tried it too, but it also doest work. I think, it did't work beacuse of i don't call dialog with show() method. Above answer works for me, thank you for your help

Comment: @ssmm will have to test that, anyways glad your problem is solved